# Conditionally fill a value in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a column in a dataframe that I need to utilize to fill another column. I have four values that could be in this column - E, H, N, and P. Each of those different values would be used to fill a value in the "Size" column.

An example of my data is as follows:

```
Type    H Data      P Data      Size
 H        1           0.5
 H       1.5           1
 E        -            -
 N        -            -
 P       0.5          0.5
 E        -            -
```

I'm wanting to fill in each row of the "Size" column.

For "E" types, I would like to fill in "2". For "N" types, I would like to fill in "-"

For "H" and "P" types, I would like to fill in a value taken from the corresponding dataframe ("H Data" or "P Data").

My result would be expected to be as shown below:

```
Type    H Data      P Data      Size
 H        1           0.5        1
 H       1.5           1        1.5
 E        -            -         2
 N        -            -         -
 P       0.5          0.5       0.5
 E        -            -         2
```

What is the best way to do this? I currently have a working code in Excel that accomplishes this, but I'm unsure of how to do it in Python. In Excel, I've got nested `IF` statements. Is it best to create a loop in Python or are there built in functions into Pandas or NumPy that can accomplish this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is too broad/vague, and possibly off-topic as a result. It sounds like you’re looking for a guide or a tutorial.

Comment: should also provide your df in a way that we can reproduce it ourselves

Comment: to answer the only question..which is 'what is the best way to do this?' I would probably say use df.apply and create a function with if statements to handle your inputs/desired outputs

Comment: voting to close the question. too broad.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using:

```
df['Size'] = df['H Data'].fillna(df['P Data'])
df.loc[df['Type'].eq('E'), 'Size'] = 2
print(df)
```

Output:

```
  Type H Data P Data Size
0    H      1    0.5    1
1    H    1.5      1  1.5
2    E      -      -    2
3    N      -      -    -
4    P    0.5    0.5  0.5
5    E      -      -    2
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. This does push me in the right direction. The "P Data" designations do not work with this code. For each row, there is "H Data" and "P Data", so the code needs to grab the correct data from the corresponding Data column. So when I review the results here, it has already inserted the "H Data" into the Size column and does not fill in the correct "P Data".

Comment: To fix this issue, I just made the four conditions with variations of the following code you posted ```df.loc[df['Type'].eq('E'), 'Size'] = 2``` Thanks for the help!